# EventSourcePolyfill vs native EventSource (Performance wise)

Tags: javascript, performance, server-sent-events, eventsource

I see a library which allows custom headers in `Header` with EventSource.

[EventSourcePolyfill](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource)

But when I see the network tab the `Type` shows `fetch` instead of `eventsource`
Whereas if I use native `EventSource` it generates type as `eventsource`.

Is there a difference in performance between `fetch` and `eventsource`.

**Using Polyfill**

```
const eventSourceInitDict = {headers: {
        'ClientId': '123123123',
        'ClientSecret': 'lllasjdlkasjdlkasdlka'
    }};
const objEventSource1 = new EventSourcePolyfill('https://*****.herokuapp.com/emit-custom-pe?userId=' + '{!$User.Id}', eventSourceInitDict);
objEventSource1.addEventListener('message', function (objEventSourceData) {
    debugger;
});
```

**Using Native EventSource**

```
const objEventSource1 = new EventSource('https://****.herokuapp.com/emit-custom-pe?userId=' + '{!$User.Id}');
objEventSource1.addEventListener('message', function (objEventSourceData) {
    debugger;
});
```